# Mexican Wave Effect in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm trying to replicate the motion of a 'mexican wave'. I am using Flash CS5, and using AS2.

I've created a 'jumper' graphic and animated it in a clip so it jumps once - up then falls back to the ground. I've pulled the clip in to the main timeline and replicated a bunch of times so I have a row of 'jumpers'. I've given each instance a unique ID. Then I'm telling each clip instance to start playing, in sequence, using the following code:

```
var total_jumpers = 36;
var i = 0;
var jumpLag = 1000;

function do_jump(bottle) {
    jumper.play();
}

for( i=1; i<=total_jumpers; i++)
{
    var mcName:String = "b" + i;
    jump = setInterval(do_jump,jumpLag,this[mcName]);
    trace("Jumper " + mcName + ". Lag: " + jumpLag);
    jumpLag += 100;
}

clearInterval(jump);

stop();
```

In the clip, I have put stop() in the last frame to try and stop it looping.

So this works ok, but the clips seem to loop – I can't get them to stop.

I would be grateful for any insight / assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` is probably not the best way to do this because it repeats continuously until `clearinterval` is called.. `setInterval` returns a different ID for each call - think of it as the unique ID for each timer.

The code which calls `clearInterval` it's actually only clearing the last interval. `clearInterval` needs to be called for each ID returned by `setInterval`. This would require storing the IDs in an array, then calling the `clearInterval` for the specific ID after the animation has started.

A better way to do this would be to use `setTimeout` (see flash.utils.setTimeout) because it only runs once and then dies, meaning you will not need the extra logic to stop the timer.